# Flowtype prototype and class throw prototype property undefined

Tags: flowtype

Trying to understand how to get classes to play nicely with prototype declarations. I prefer them because of memory saving. I get an error here that types is not defined on MyClass. How do I predefine prototype on classes?

```
//@flow
class MyClass {
    x: number;
    constructor(){
        this.x = 1
    }
}

(MyClass.prototype.types: Object);

MyClass.prototype.types = {};

const x : number = MyClass.prototype.types;
```